# what is the difference between these two systems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

what is the difference between these two pulley systems when calculating the angular acceleration if the moment of inertia and radius is the same?
[image]

Comment: @HariPrasad there is a different angular acceleration for each system

Comment: @Joe: correct. Both systems are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In left diagram the force F is creating a torque and only the pulley is being accelerated.

In the right hand diagram both the mass and the pulley are being accelerated by the weight of the mass.
The tension in the string is less that the weight of the mass as the mass is accelerating downwards.
So the angular acceleration of the pulley will be less in this case.

Comment: does that mean the left diagram has no tension, if so why?

Comment: @Joe No.  The string tension in the left hand diagram is F whereas that in the right hand diagram is less than F because the weight of the mass has to accelerate the weight as well as the pulley wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. Take the second one and split the rope with an equal and opposite force $F$ on each side

[image: fbd]

If the mass is not moving then $F=m g$, but when the mass is accelerating it is not. Why? Because if $a$ is the acceleration of the mass then the balance of forces is $$F - m g =m a$$

Comment: does that mean the left diagram has no tension, if so why?

Comment: No it does not mean this. You clearly see the tension on the left being $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a $y$-axis pointing downwards.

Right hand case:

Translation of the mass:

$$ma_y=mg-F$$

Rotation of the cylinder:

$$I\alpha=FR$$

$$a_y=\alpha R$$

$$\alpha=\frac{a_y}{R}$$

With some substitutions we then get:

$$a_y=\frac{mg}{m+\frac{I}{R^2}}=\frac{mgR^2}{mR^2+I}$$

In the left hand case:

$$I\alpha=FR$$

$$\alpha=\frac{FR}{I}$$

$$a_y=\frac{FR^2}{I}$$

And since $$F=mg$$

$$a_y=\frac{mgR^2}{I}$$

So the linear and angular acceleration are smaller in the right hand case.